# jQuery incorrectly reports a width of zero

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to access the width of certain elements by using jQuery's `.width()` function, but sometimes the return value is `0` when I don't expect it. Is this a known issue? Does an element have to be visible for this to work, perhaps? If there are limitations, how can I work around them?

Comment: I would expect the width of collapsed or hidden elements to be zero or `NaN` (i.e. undefined).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're dealing with images, make sure to run the code in `$(window).load()` rather than `$(document).ready()`, like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  var width = $("img").width();
});
```

Otherwise, make sure the element is visible, hidden elements have no [`.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) or [`.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) (it'll return 0 for both).

Comment: Would you suggest making the element in question visible before getting the width and then re-hiding it? Or is there a better workaround?

Comment: @Pieter - You can give it a relative position way off the page, or just show/hide it...remember that JavaScript has to pause for the UI thread to update, so the user won't see a blink when you do this :)

Comment: I chose to set `display` to `block` but keeping `visibility` set to `hidden` so that I can get the width without risking that the user can see the element even for a split second.

Answer (score 1):

The element has to have loaded.. try binding it on window load

```
$(window).load(function(){  alert('#img').width()   });
```

You can also try explicitly defining a width through css on the element I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if image is visible with this extra condition

```
$(window).load(function(){  if($("#img").is(":visible"))alert('#img').width()   });
```